# I was accused of cheating on an online physics exam because my answers were similar to those on Chegg

Tags: exams, cheating, online-learning

Today I was found guilty because my exam answers were similar to those on the math website. I haven't even seen the evidence(Chegg's answers) they said. I would like some advice on the appeal.

Here is what happened.

There were 2 questions they suspected. In the first question, I put an absolute sign on my answer to eliminate the direction of water flow because the question provided the flow direction so that I didn't need to consider the direction. I think the official answer didn't have the absolute sign but Chegg's answer had. In the second question, I used an equation that is slightly different from my lecture note because I learned that from the internet and it is more accurate(the difference is due to different coursebooks). I think Chegg's answer used the same equation I did.

I have explained the reasons why I answered like this and provided the note I learned from the internet with the equation I used. The committee didn't challenge my statement at that time. It turns out they found me guilty.

What reason can I use to appeal this result and claim my innocence?

Comment: Sorry to hear you are in this situation. I suspect your next steps will depend on your university's appeal process (which will be difficult for us to advise you on, since every university has its own process).

Comment: I think you're going to have a rough time proving your innocence if you used equations not taught in the course. Have you used the modified equations in previous work like an assignment?

Comment: @Cell - really? Students should not use anything but exactly what was provided in the official course materials? I guess I should not have been reading all those other textbooks to see different ways to approach problems...

Comment: Worth a read: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/148236/72855

Comment: Can you explain what "found guilty" exactly means and what else you might do now? Also, what exactly is this "comitee"? Is it in general just?

Comment: @JonCuster You're exaggerating. We all read other material besides what's taught in lectures to learn, but there is a difference between  new conceptual approaches and straight up using different equations especially if they can't be derived from the lecture ones. And doing so wont put you in a favorable position like this one.

Comment: @Cell - of course I was exaggerating, generally to good effect however. The whole point of reading more broadly is to find and understand other approaches, particularly ones that resonate better (for whatever reason) with you. Those may, or may not, involve different 'equations'.

Comment: To follow @cag51's comment, the first thing you should do is find out all you can about the process and what resources are available to you.  At my university, this would be communicated to you by the Integrity office (who should be handling this) and I believe you would have support from a student-run organization.

Comment: Do you know for a fact that there is a formal appeal process at your institution? There's probably no way to conjure an "appeal" out of thin air if no such process is defined at your school.

Comment: Thay said I can appeal with proper reasons within 7 working days. I'd like to challenge that 1) I have never seen any evidence they found, I don't have a chance to respond to it. 2) I have clearly explained my working steps that led to the answers and no one challenged my statement. I also provided my study note with the equation I used. And they found me guilty. Isn't it a presumption of guilt? 3)I have followed the rules to record my self and my screen when I took the exam with a TA's monitoring, I was not able to cheat online. 4) They cannot prove I can't reach the answer except cheating.

Comment: @user111388 They said the act of cheating was established. I can appeal now. The committee reviews the evidence and my explanation then voted if I cheat or not.

Comment: Do you have a "lawyer"? Have you talked to your student union? Also, why is the question closed? And is it in general a fair process? (Eg we had mighty profs who could just say "you cheated" if they don't like you  and it counted as proven -- then my advises would be different).

Comment: @user111388 The question closed for individual factors. I am not able to afford a lawyer. And my student union is not responding. They said the committee is formed by 6 profs, I think it should be fair.

Comment: @ChrisLin: I am sorry about the question being closed. I don't neccessarily mean a real lawyer, but someone knowledgeable who helps you.