# I need help please about being accused on cheating

Tags: graduate-school

My prof is accusing me of chatting on an Online exam. I did not cheat. The exam was 30 multiple-choice and 3 short answers.
I got all MCQ right, except I made some mistakes in the short answer.
In the exam, His concern only on the last 3 short answer questions.  he claimed that he cheats from the test bank ( Answer key of the test book). Also, he claimed that I answered one question similar to the textbook; however, this question's answer included only simple mathematical addition of some numbers. This does not show any valid reasons for his accusation. Moreover, during the meeting, he blamed me for choosing the wrong answer for a question. Thus, I am being blamed for answering questions, whether they are right or wrong. and another question was because I answered similar to the test bank  as he was like," this part of the question was not in the test bank)

Secondly, he accused me of violating academic Integrity in my online quizzes, and his concern was, "My other concern is that you spent on average 18 minutes on all online quizzes following the first quiz that included short answers, whereas the class spent anywhere between 40 minutes to 2 hours. The majority of students use a second attempt to improve their score on the first attempt." Note: all the quizzes are theory 30 MCQ, except the first quiz was 25 MCQ and 1 short-answer.
He sent me an email to discuss, and then during the online meeting, he asks me to do an oral exam." he was like, so I can prove some evidence,"  and I refused to make the oral exam as it's unfair to be exam orally for something I don't do it.
He gave me zero on the midterm and put me under academic integrity. Please advise me what I should do? I have my review of the hearing next week.

Comment: Or this: [Accused of cheating on online exams](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/148236/accused-of-cheating-on-online-exams)

Comment: "*he claimed that he cheats from the test bank*"  Your professor actually confessed to you that he cheated?

Comment: Other than that your professor pointed out that you answered the multiple choice part mich faster than anyone else, I find what happened and what they objected to impossible to understand as presented here.

Comment: As written, this is likely to be closed as a duplicate of the linked questions. However, you could consider editing to focus on the prof's offer of taking an oral exam to clear your name -- I think that is a unique element.

Answer (score 2):

> He sent me an email to discuss, and then during the online meeting, he asks me to do an oral exam.

You present this as a bad thing, but it's actually a good thing.

Apparently you did all the tests unusually fast, and in a way that looks to an observer like you're cheating. But that's not enough proof. It's possible that you're just pretty good at this subject. So the professor needs to test whether you cheated or whether you're just really good and fast at this subject.

That's what the oral exam is for. If you know this subject really well, you should also be able to do well in the oral exam.

Comment: I worry about this answer. If the prof is hostile, as it seems, and administers the oral, it is hard to be assured of fairness. I would have fewer concerns if the oral was administered by a third party.

Comment: Yeah that's fair, the question sounds like there's already been arguing back and forth, so a more neutral third party, at least as an observer, is desirable. But "we may want to have an oral follow-up exam" is pretty common nowadays when professors need to confirm whether someone really did an assignment (or online test) themselves and understands their own answers.